# Mongodb/Mongoose - Aggregation to group all matching docs in same collection in an array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am in a scenario where I want to find some similar documents and group them in an array.
Here is an example to illustrate better the idea:

Documents in collection:

```
{
   _id: 0,
   enabled: false,
   name:"name A",
   amounts:{ salary: 100 },
   field_condition: "No",
   created_A: "2020-07-01"
}

{
   _id: 1,
   enabled: false,
   name:"name A",
   amounts:{ salary: 100 },
   field_condition: "Yes",
   created_A: "2020-08-01"
}

{
   _id: 2,
   enabled: false,
   name:"name A",
   amounts:{ salary: 100 }, 
   field_condition: "Yes",
   created_A: "2020-09-01"
}

{
   _id: 3,
   enabled: true,
   name:"name A",
   amounts:{ salary: 100 }, 
   field_condition: "No",
   created_A: "2020-10-01"
}



{
   _id: 4,
   enabled: false,
   name:"name B",
   amounts:{ salary: 100 },
   field_condition: "No",
   created_A: "2020-07-01"
}

{
   _id: 5,
   enabled: false,
   name:"name B",
   amounts:{ salary: 100 },
   field_condition: "Yes",
   created_A: "2020-08-01"
}

{
   _id: 6,
   enabled: false,
   name:"name B",
   amounts:{ salary: 100 }, 
   field_condition: "Yes",
   created_A: "2020-09-01",

}

{
   _id: 7,
   enabled: true,
   name:"name B",
   amounts:{ salary: 100 }, 
   field_condition: "No",
   created_A: "2020-10-01"
}
```

I want to find all documents where the enabled field is `true`and field_condition is equal to `No` that would result to these two documents:

```
{
   _id: 3,
   enabled: true,
   name:"name A",
   amounts:{ salary: 100 }, 
   field_condition: "No",
   created_A: "2020-10-01"
}

{
   _id: 7,
   enabled: true,
   name:"name B",
   amounts:{ salary: 100 }, 
   field_condition: "No",
   created_At: "2020-10-01"
}
```

Then, I want to recursively find the documents of the previous months, that match the `name` field, `enabled: false` and `field_condition: "Yes"` till I reach one where `field_condition: "No"` and stop. Then I want to put the found documents of previous month, in an array of the actual document:

```
[ 
 {
   _id: 3,
   enabled: true,
   name:"name A",
   amounts:{ salary: 100 }, 
   field_condition: "No",
   created_A: "2020-10-01",
   relatedDocs: [
      {
         _id: 1,
         enabled: false,
         name:"name A",
         amounts:{ salary: 100 },
         field_condition: "Yes",
         created_A: "2020-08-01"
      },

      {
         _id: 2,
         enabled: false,
         name:"name A",
         amounts:{ salary: 100 }, 
         field_condition: "Yes",
         created_A: "2020-09-01"
      }
   ]
},


{
   _id: 7,
   enabled: true,
   name:"name B",
   amounts:{ salary: 100 }, 
   field_condition: "No",
   created_At: "2020-10-01",
   relatedDocs: [
      {
         _id: 1,
         enabled: false,
         name:"name B",
         amounts:{ salary: 100 },
         field_condition: "Yes",
         created_A: "2020-08-01"
      },

      {
         _id: 2,
         enabled: false,
         name:"name B",
         amounts:{ salary: 100 }, 
         field_condition: "Yes",
         created_A: "2020-09-01"
      }
   ]
 }
]
```

I tried so hard with the `$lookup`aggregation but could not get it to work.
Your help is much appreciated .
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is not straight forward to achieve.

[play](https://mongoplayground.net/p/jKmTX_IpnW4)

You can have entire data sorted with the desired order.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {//add a field to sort
      "consider": {
        $and: [
          {
            "$eq": [
              "$enabled",
              true
            ]
          },
          {
            $eq: [
              "$field_condition",
              "No"
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      "date": {
        "$dateFromString": {
          "dateString": "$created_A"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: { //sort the data
      "consider": -1,
      "date": -1
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {//group by name and data will have sorted result
      "_id": "$name",
      "data": {
        $push: "$$ROOT"
      },
      "considerDoc": {
        $first: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

If you are sure that every month will have an entry and only latest months will have `Yes` in that field condition, then you can filter it in another stage.

Otherwise you have to do it in the backend code.